# Open page from main.js and pass data to it

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to create a very simple test addon that does one thing: open an html page (located in the data folder) from main.js, then pass it some generated JSON that it can display. I've figured out a very complex way to do this using message-passing and cloning unsafeWindow.options, but there must be a simpler way?

ps. I'm happy to use the 'addon-page' module if this is the right way to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple template for opening a tab, then when tab is ready, attach content scripts, pass some parameters, and setup message handlers:

In addon module:

```
var resourceURL=require("sdk/self").data.url;
require("sdk/tabs").open({
    url:resourceURL("index.html"),
    onReady:function(tab){
        var worker=tab.attach({
            contentScriptFile:["support.js","content.js"].map(resourceURL),
            contentScriptOptions:{},    //parameters passed to content script
        });
        worker.port.on("ready",function(msgIn){
            worker.port.emit("acknowledge",msgOut);
        });
    }
});
```

And in the content script; To send a "ready" message and recieve "acknowledge" message:

```
self.port.on("acknowledge",function(msgIn){});
self.port.emit("ready",msgOut);
```

---

There might be changes to the handling of parameters `url` and/or `contentScriptFile`, such that relative paths are allowed without the need for require("sdk/self").data.url.  Not sure if this just speculation/proposal or if it's currently implemented; Haven't checked.

Also I think `addon-page` is depreciated and hasn't worked since the upgrade to australis UI (i.e. navigation bar is no longer hidden for special URIs like *about:addons*).

Comment: @EpokK I have no idea what you are talking about.  From where or who are you accusing me of copying from?  I just looked at some of my old code for guidance (old as it long before I was ever on SO).

Answer (score 0):

You can use port to send data in an other view like this:

**main.js**

```
// Create a menu panel
var menu = panels.Panel({
  contentURL: data.url("menu.html"),
  contentScriptFile: data.url("menu.js"),
});

// Your data
var data = {animal: 'panda'};
menu.port.emit('data', JSON.stringify(data));
```

**menu.js**

```
self.port.on('data', function onReceiveData(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: I'm pretty certain the original questioner wanted to open a new tab and load content files (html, scripts) into the tab.  Also you should probably `JSON.stringify(data)` before sending it via `menu.port.emit` if you intend to use the data for something other than console.log.

Comment: Yes, I need to open the html page in a normal tab, not in a panel.